# excel macro vba on vlookup formula

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am new to excel macro. I wanted to create a macro for vlookup so that I can apply to many cells but it doesn't work.

```
Sub haha()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws, ws1 As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)
wb.Activate

ws1.Select

Range("E1").Formula = "=+VLOOKUP(" & ws1.Range("C6") & "," & ws.Range("c7:d10") & ",2,FALSE)"

End sub
```

I wanted to look up a value in my current sheet to another sheet's range to return a unique value. Please help! :)

Comment: put `.Address` after you two ranges in the vlookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace these 3 lines:

```
wb.Activate
ws1.Select
Range("E1").Formula = "=+VLOOKUP(" & ws1.Range("C6") & "," & ws.Range("c7:d10") & ",2,FALSE)"
```

with this:

```
ws1.Range("E1").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C6," & ws.Range("C7:D10").Address(External:=1) & ",2,FALSE)"
```

In the `ws1.Range("C6")` part the `sheet` and `address` are not needed, in this case, as the cell is in the same sheet where the formula goes so `ws1.Range("C6")` will always return `C6`.

As for the `ws.Range("c7:d10")` part you need the "external reference" because it refers to another sheet. Although the `External` reference of the `Range.Address Property` includes the filename, it gets dropped as the formula goes in the same workbook.

Comment: Hi EEM, this alternative also works well!1 I have alot to learn from you guys! :) Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you use `.Address(External:=1)` no need to add the  `.Worksheet.Name` part as the address function will include it.

Comment: Noted with thanks! Just a quick question. I learned macro and vba from textbook. But whenever I apply in real life, I will encounter some problems.  How do we improve on our macro skills such that we are able to help others in this forum? Any websites, videos or books to recommend.

Comment: When writing your code you can always use the help button (F1) it will take to the Microsoft site and will provide information about that particular command, function, statement, etc. There are also good sites i.e [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com),http://spreadsheetpage.com/,
http://excelexperts.com/, 
http://www.jkp-ads.com/, 
http://www.bigresource.com/, 
http://www.mrexcel.com/, 
http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/

Answer (score 2):

Check this out.

```
Sub haha()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)
wb.Activate

Set rng = ws.Range("c7:d10")
ws1.Range("E1").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & ws1.Range("C6").Address & "," & rng.Worksheet.Name & "!" & rng.Address & ",2,FALSE)"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi both, It works perfectly! Just an enquiry - why do we use .Worksheet.Name and .Address in the vlookup? Thanks alot! :)

Comment: Because in lookuparray we must provide the sheet name from which it belongs.

Comment: Thanks alot! Really appreciate the help!